# How to wrap large text in a table and display it on mouse hover as a popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Can this be done using only HTML and CSS?
Below is the code I tried. The problem is on mouse hover it displays it in the same cell and changes the width of the tables. Is there a way to display the text as a popover?

```css
table td.text {
  max-width: 10px;
}

table td.text span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

table td.text span:hover {
  background-color: #BDE5F8;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  height: auto;
  /* just added this line */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text"><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></td>
    <td class="text"><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></td>
    <td class="text"><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `position:absolute;` to make the text get out of the flow when you hover over it

```css
table td.text {
  max-width: 10px;
  
}

table td.text span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
table td.text:hover span:not(.empty) {
  background-color: #BDE5F8;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  height: auto;
  /* just added this line */
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text"><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></td>
    <td class="text"><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></td>
    <td class="text"><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></td>
    <td class="text"><span class="empty"></span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This works but, one problem is if my cell does not have any text then on hover it should not display anything. In this case it would still display the element

Comment: @Steven.lin if there is no text then it won't display anything.. see my edit !

Comment: Agreed in your snippet it does not show up. But in order for it have a better look and feel, I added a border and padding in the CSS and that causes it show up even when there is no text in the cell. Do you think there is a workaround this problem. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Steven.lin is it possible for you to add a class for td or span to define the empty cells ?

Comment: I have no idea how I can do that.

Comment: @Steven.lin if you are generating the text dynamically.. then you should check if the span has content (innerHTML) .. and if it doesn't you add a class (empty) .. and in the css you use `table td.text:hover span:not(.empty)`

Comment: Aah. I see that makes sense, I got that to work.  One last issue, if the cell does not have large text, and there is no word wrap, even then this code displays the text on hover. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: This may be done with javascript.. give different class according to text size.. and then use the class instead of using the span tag in css selector

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```css
.expand {
  max-width : 50px; 
  white-space : nowrap;
  overflow : hidden;
}

.expand:hover {
  max-width : initial; 
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>Lorem</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <strong>Ipsum</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td class="expand">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use title attribute, and not use that hover css. I replicate code here just for show you a way, but you should use javascript to manipulate your text data into title attribute instead of using replication here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        table td.text {
            max-width: 10px;
        }

        table td.text span {
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="text" title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
        </td>
        <td class="text" title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
        </td>
        <td class="text" title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're looking for `tooltips` or `popovers`, 
these feature have to be implemented via javascript because you will better handle positioning (imagine when your element is close to a border) or, delaying opening/closing.

Bootstrap has these features:

1. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers
2. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

but I imagine there are plenty of them over github!

Comment: title attribute do the work pretty well without those js components

Comment: tooltips are thought to replace *title attr hover behaviour* allowing for html support, styling, ecc.. `[title]` is the default provided by the browser, like `alert` or `prompt` but sometimes your UI Design/Experience requires something more sophisticated.

Comment: yeah that's true